# Python - How to get the start/base address of a process?

Tags: python, windows, process, ctypes, pywin32

How do I get the start/base address of a process? Per example Solitaire.exe (solitaire.exe+BAFA8)

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes, win32ui, win32process


PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
HWND = win32ui.FindWindow(None,u"Solitär").GetSafeHwnd()
PID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND)[1]
PROCESS = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,PID)

print PID, HWND,PROCESS
```

I would like to calculate a memory address and for this way I need the base address of solitaire.exe.

Here's a picture of what I mean:

[image: memory address]

Comment: I don't know what you mean actually: the memory address of the entry of the program or the file path of the exe file?

Comment: @Rubby: the memory address of the entry of the program. But I don't know how. somthing with win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)? When I found out the address I have to add a static offset (0xBAFA8) ==> to get a new address...

Answer (score 2):

I think the handle returned by [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is actually the base address of the given module. You get the handle of the exe by passing NULL.

Answer (score 1):

**Install pydbg**

Source: https://github.com/OpenRCE/pydbg

Unofficial binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pydbg

```
from pydbg import *
from pydbg.defines import *

import struct

dbg = pydbg()

path_exe = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe"

dbg.load(path_exe, "-u amir")
dbg.debug_event_loop()

parameter_addr = dbg.context.Esp #(+ 0x8)

print 'ESP (address) ',parameter_addr


#attach not working under Win7 for me

#pid = raw_input("Enter PID:")
#print 'PID entered %i'%int(pid)
#dbg.attach(int(pid)) #attaching to running process not working
```

You might want to have a look at PaiMei, although it's not very active right now https://github.com/OpenRCE/paimei

I couldn't get attach() to work and used load instead. Pydbg has loads of functionality, such as read_proccess_memory, write_process_memory etc.

Note that you can't randomly change memory, because an operating system protects memory of other processes from your process (protected mode). Before the x86 processors there were some which allowed all processors to run in real mode, i.e. the full access of memory for every programm. Non-malicious software usually (always?) doesn't read/write other processes' memory.

Answer (score 1):

The HMDOULE value of [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the base address of the loaded module and is probably the address you need to compute the offset.

If not, that address is the start of the header of the module (DLL/EXE), which can be displayed with the `dumpbin` utility that comes with Visual Studio or you can interpret it yourself using the [Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125) to determine the `AddressOfEntryPoint` and `BaseOfCode` as offsets from the base address.  If the base address of the module isn't what you need, one of these two is another option.

Example:

```
>>> BaseAddress = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None) + 0xBAFA8
>>> print '{:08X}'.format(BaseAddress)
1D0BAFA8
```

If The `AddressOfEntryPoint` or `BaseOfCode` is needed, you'll have to use `ctypes` to call `ReadProcessMemory` following the PE specification to locate the offsets, or just use `dumpbin /headers solitaire.exe` to learn the offsets.

Comment: Hi, I am using now EnumProcessModules (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682633.aspx). But the problem is now that I only get 32-bit handles...

Comment: Is your process a 32-bit process?  You'll need to be 64-bit to get 64-bit handles.

Comment: Hi, my process is a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use frida to easy do that.
It is very useful to make hack and do some memory operation just like make address offset, read memory, write something to special memory etc...
https://github.com/frida/frida

2021.08.01 update:
Thanks for @Simas Joneliunas reminding

There some step using frida(windows):

1. Install frida by pip

```
pip install frida-tools # CLI tools
pip install frida       # Python bindings
```

2. Using frida api

```
session = frida.attach(processName)
script = session.create_script("""yourScript""")
script.load()
sys.stdin.read() #make program always alive
session.detach()
```

3. Edit your scrip(using JavaScrip)

```
var baseAddr = Module.findBaseAddress('solitaire.exe');
var firstPointer = baseAddr.add(0xBAFA8).readPointer();
var secondPointer = firstPointer.add(0x50).readPointer();
var thirdPointer = secondPointer.add(0x14).readPointer();
#if your target pointer points to a Ansi String, you can use #thirdPointer.readAnsiString() to read
```

The official site https://frida.re/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32333618)